# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. > Failed to execute aapt

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Get this error trying to build android apk in my ionic app. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 11s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\KING WOODE\Documents\Mobile Apps\test\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
(node:7044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7044) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Did you read the words in the error message? It seems pretty clear and concise. Start at the very last line and read upward. It shouldn't take you more than about 30 seconds to spot the problem description. The messages aren't there simply to take up space on your screen.

Comment: Am new to this .that is why am asking for help :) . Will really appreciate if you offer a solution . Thanks

Comment: The solution is given in the last two sentences in that error message. We don't have your code. You do. *Read the words in  those two sentences.*

Answer (score 0):

change

```
'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

with

```
'com.android.support:support-v4:"android sdk version you using"'
```

in plugin.xml files in plugins folder and node_modules folder.

Then do the same in project.properites in 'platform android'