# Ionic - Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

I got this error during runtime of my Ionic Application. I was trying to implement the Ionic "Email Composer" library to send emails from the client side, please reference this link to learn about the code that I am following; https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer.
The flow of the error was when I was testing the application I hit a button that triggers the "LoadingDialog" function this function triggers the "SendEmail" function which is where the error occurs. I am not sure how to fix this error, but I think it has to do with the syntax of a promise that I don't understand yet. Thank you for any help you can provide!

### Lines of code that appear in the error

> this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{
> //<<<<<<<< THIS IS LINE 221 IN home.page.ts file and it appears in the error

> this.SendEmail(); //<<<<<<<< THIS IS LINE 109 IN home.page.ts file

### Error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
     at HomePage.SendEmail (home.page.ts:221)
     at HomePage.<anonymous> (home.page.ts:109)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:70)
     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
     at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
     at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
     at zone-evergreen.js:855
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
     at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
     at zone-evergreen.js:707
     at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:70)
     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
     at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
     at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
     at zone-evergreen.js:855
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
```

### Code (home.page.ts)

```
            import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';
    
            export class HomePage {
    
            constructor(private http: Http, public loadingController: LoadingController,
                    public alertController: AlertController, 
                    private emailComposer: EmailComposer) {
           //constructor
            }
        async LoadingDialog(httpformdata) {//loading circle symbol
            const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
                message: 'Please wait...',
                duration: null
            });
            this.loading = loading;
            this.loading.present();
            console.log('ion dialog created.');
            /***  SendEmail  ***/
            this.SendEmail(); //<<<<<<<< THIS IS LINE 109 IN home.page.ts file
            /***  GET REQUEST  ***/
            this.GET_request(httpformdata);
            /***  POST REQUEST  ***/
            //this.POST_request(httpformdata);
            console.log('request made in async.');
            
            //this.loading.dismiss();
            //console.log('ion dialog dismissed.');
    
            const { role, data } = await loading.onDidDismiss();
    
            console.log('Loading dismissed!');
        }
            async RegularAlert(the_header: String, the_message: String) {//customized alert() dialog
            const alert = await this.alertController.create({
                header: '' + the_header,
                message: '' + the_message,
                buttons: ['OK']
            });
            await alert.present();
            return alert.getAttribute("header");
        }
    
        SendEmail(){
                this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) =>{  //<<<<<<<< THIS IS LINE 221 IN home.page.ts file
                    if(available) {
                    //Now we know we can send
                    this.RegularAlert("testing the isAvailable().then", "available is true");//print a debug message to test functionality of   
    
                    let email = {
                        to:'max@mustermann.de',
                        cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
                        bcc: [],
                        attachments: [],
                        subject: 'Cordova Icons',
                        body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
                        isHtml: false
                      }
                    
                      // Send a text message using default options
                      this.emailComposer.open(email);
                    }
                    else{
                        this.RegularAlert("testing the isAvailable().then", "available is false");
                    }
                });
            
        } 
    
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `then()` on the value returned by `this.emailComposer.isAvailable()`. ANd the error message tells you that you can't call `.then()` on undefined. What do you conclude?

Comment: looks like I need to add a window.plugin check around the this.emailComposer.isAvailable() promise call, just like this guy https://youtu.be/kFfNTdJXVok?t=190, The only problem that I can see is that his ionic is running angularjs where mine is running angular 4? what do you think @JB Nizet

Comment: I think that this.emailComposer.isAvailable() is returning undefined instad of returning a promise as it should, and that you should thus fix the code of this method.

Comment: Visual Studio code says that the "plugins" library is not found on "window" variable, I think this is because it was for angularjs only. For me I am running Angular 4 so what I can use is "if(this.platform.is('cordova')){//use this for android,iOS,Windows-Mobile,etc" since the guy in youtu.be/kFfNTdJXVok?t=190 said he added "window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer" because he knows the plugins aren't available in the web browser, which is where I was testing my code in(web brower) when I got the error. I will test the email composer on my android phone to see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I did not run the app in the emulator or on a Android phone, since the Cordova library only runs with Mobile OS's like Android OS, so the this.emailComposer.isAvailable() was undefined instead of returning a promise. The minimum that you need is:

> if (this.platform.is('cordova')){
> //run your email composer code here
> }

This code worked for me after I ran the code on a android phone:

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')){//use cordova for android,iOS,Windows-Mobile,etc
                this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: 
                   boolean) =>{
                                //CODE HERE
                  
                            });
}else{
      console.log("Platform is not cordova/mobile","You are running in browser, this.emailComposer.isAvailable() is undefined.");
}
```

Here is the source code for the email composer: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure weather you found the source of the problem yet. But the problem is related to your env, **you need to test in your emulator / phone in order to avoid this exception**.

Comment: Greetings Faouzi, thank you for your answer, I have been trying to test the app on a android phone, but I can't because I am getting a build error when I try to build the android apk with the ionic command line using command: ionic cordova build android

Comment: Have you tried to solve the error showing while trying to build your app ? you're surely missing something in your code

Comment: I didn't make any other changes other than add the email composer library to the ng module folder and add the code for email composer in the relevant file. I have had problems with ionic not building android app before. I am pretty certain that it's something with ionic because the app builds in the web browser.

Comment: 1- Have you been able to build your apk before adding the mail composer ?
2- Did you debug why ionic can't build the apk ? just go back and read the log and you'll see the file causing the problem with the exacte line

Comment: I did not figure out the exact problem but the error I had was on here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49641291/3576562 , everything was the same except for my error did not specify any lines of source code nor configuration files that needed changes. My solution was that I created a new bare project and remembered to run "npm update" and updated my app-root component html file because ionic updated some libraries that prevented my tabs from functioning. So I am thinking that ionic updated which prevented my ionic app from building the android sdk apk, which "npm update" fixed by

Comment: modifying the "node modules" folder and ionic project config files. Anyways I was able to get the ionic app to load on my phone and email composer worked on my phone, so your answer and @JB Nizet answer were both right. The only issue I had with email composer is that it prompts the user to use installed local email app (like gmail, yahoo), which was not what I was trying to accomplish. I want to send email in the background from the ionic app programmed in the typescript that ionic provides, because I want to save money on a server.